# Compiling an SQL function - error: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following: case

Tags: oracle, plsql

I was trying to compile the following function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION where_to_save(v_part_dynam OUT CLOB)
RETURN CLOB
IS
BEGIN 
  CASE
      WHEN LDR_SUBTYPE = ('IEC') THEN v_part_dynam := v_part_dynam || 'SUBPARTITION SP0 VALUES (IEC)';

      ELSE  v_part_dynam := v_part_dynam || 'SUBPARTITION SP1 VALUES (OTHER)';
  END
   RETURN v_part_dynam;   

END where_to_save;
```

The script output prints out the function has been compiled but there's an error

```
FUNCTION WHERE_TO_SAVE compiled
Errors: check compiler log
```

The error is a PLS-00103

```
Error(10,4): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:     case
```

I don't know why this is happening, I can't just add a CASE just because... What's the problem?

Comment: @TMcKeown: why do you think they are wrong? A `;` is used to terminate (=mark the end of) a SQL statement. All the `;` in the question are required.

Comment: ooops.... this is ORACLE...  i thought this was SQL SERVER

Comment: @TMcKeown: you should use `;` in SQL Server the same way: https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons

Comment: as you can guess, I don't write UDF's...  lol, but yes I see that you are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assignment should come before the `case`, and in PL/SQL you could use an `if`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION where_to_save(v_part_dynam OUT CLOB)
RETURN CLOB
IS
BEGIN 
  if LDR_SUBTYPE = ('IEC')
  then
    v_part_dynam := v_part_dynam || 'SUBPARTITION SP0 VALUES (IEC)';
  else
    v_part_dynam := v_part_dynam || 'SUBPARTITION SP1 VALUES (OTHER)';
  end if;

  RETURN v_part_dynam;   
END where_to_save;
```

Or if you prefer `case`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION where_to_save(v_part_dynam OUT CLOB)
RETURN CLOB
IS
BEGIN 
  case
  when LDR_SUBTYPE = ('IEC')
  then v_part_dynam := v_part_dynam
       || 'SUBPARTITION SP0 VALUES (IEC)';
  else v_part_dynam := v_part_dynam
       || 'SUBPARTITION SP1 VALUES (OTHER)';
  end case;
  RETURN v_part_dynam;   
END where_to_save;
```

Also, `LDR_SUBTYPE` isn't defined in your code. It should. This signature would work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION where_to_save(LDR_SUBTYPE varchar, v_part_dynam OUT CLOB)
```

Comment: Yes, I know it's not, thanks, this works fine but why is the if better than case?

Comment: @MyNameIsRui: It really depends on the type of condition. If you check for multiple values of one column only, a `case` would fit best. For simple `if` `else` or complex statements, `if` is preffered.

Comment: The case is there for posterior conditions :)

Comment: @MyNameIsRui: Updated. Now you have both.

Answer (score 2):

The specific problem with your code is that, when used as a PL/SQL statement, `CASE` must be terminated with `END CASE;`.

```
BEGIN 
  CASE
      WHEN LDR_SUBTYPE = ('IEC') THEN v_part_dynam := v_part_dynam || 'SUBPARTITION SP0 VALUES (IEC)';

      ELSE  v_part_dynam := v_part_dynam || 'SUBPARTITION SP1 VALUES (OTHER)';
  END CASE;

  RETURN v_part_dynam;   

END where_to_save;
```